# Visual studio code auto completion when typing in {

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, typescript, editor

I'm using Visual studio code to edit .ts files but whenever I type in { it shows a whole list of suggestions like below. When hitting enter, word 'abstract' will be inserted into the cursor location.

What I'd expect is when typing in {, the other part of the brace, }, will be inserted into the editor as well automatically. This is what happens when typing in ( and [, but the behavior is just different when inputting {.

Also given { is a frequently used character, so this bugs me much. Not sure if this is configurable or not. Please shed some light on it.

triggers auto completion suggestions
[image]

Comment: Sorry guys, it turned out to be a problem of 'Vim' extension I installed. That is a vi simulator which makes the usage of editor the same as vi. Once I uninstalled vim extension the issue has gone. I'll see if that is a known issue of vim extension or not.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a known issue of Vim extension of Visual Studio Code.

Here is the issue lodged in github:
https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/194 
https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/188

As of now the issue has not been solved.